# Select all shapes in word automation with C sharp

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

How can I select all shapes in a document with C#.

I'm currently changing the language settings of a word document.

I was able to change the language using select all, unfortunately not all were selected like header/footer, text box or any shapes on the document. I manage somehow to set the language in header/footer. But I can't find a way to set the language for shapes.

I have tried to do a quick macro, but I don't know what the index for each shapes in the document.

This is the macro:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("Text Box 4").Select
ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 4", "Rectangle 7")).Select
ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 4", "Rectangle 7", _
    "Text Box 10")).Select
ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("Text Box 4", "Rectangle 7", _
    "Text Box 10", "Rectangle 11")).Select
Selection.LanguageID = wdEnglishUK
```

And this is what I deed in C#, but its not working...

```
        wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.SelectAll();
        wordApp.Selection.LanguageID = Word.WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK;
```

If try using this:

```
wordApp.ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(??).Select; //I don't know what should I put inside the range
wordApp.Selection.LanguageID = Word.WdLanguageID.wdEnglishUK;
```

I hope someone here can help me. Or if you have better solution to change the language, please let me know.Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not had an answer in a while, so here is VBA, I hope you can convert it.

> This one takes care of language change
>   for the whole document, including
>   headers and footers and other
>   "stories", and text boxes as well as
>   shapes with text.

```
Sub langconvPL()
Dim mystoryrange As Range
For Each mystoryrange In ActiveDocument.StoryRanges
mystoryrange.LanguageID = wdPolish
mystoryrange.NoProofing = False
Next mystoryrange

scount = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Count

For x = 1 To scount
ActiveDocument.Shapes(x).Select
If ActiveDocument.Shapes(x).TextFrame.HasText = True Then
ActiveDocument.Shapes(x).TextFrame.TextRange.Select
Selection.LanguageID = wdPolish
End If
Next x
End Sub
```

From: http://www.proz.com/forum/office_applications/31516-how_to_change_textbox_language_in_a_word_document.html

Comment: What I've found is that you can't necessarily rely on the SHAPES collection to return ALL the shapes in the document. Often, i've had to iterate through all the storyRanges, all the sections, the headers and footers FOR EACH section, and all the textboxes in all of the above in order to account for all the possible shapes in a document. remou's code is a good start at that.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I manage to convert it and its working now. @drventure your correct I need iterate all through the storyRanges, etc.. But there was one thing went wrong after I changed the language. The spelling and grammar are not automatically checked even upon loading the document, this only affect range that I've converted. I don't know why it happen and I have read some article for the restriction of automation object mode. Anyway thanks again and I think I'll post it as another question.